# ServiceStack ORMLite encoding issue after upgrade

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

We have just upgraded some software we have from ServiceStack 4.0.62 to ServiceStack 5.0.0.0.

For some reason ormlite's encoding management seem to have changed.

Code that simply saves a DTO with a string field containing special characters (e.g Ø ← ↑ → ↓ ↔ ↕~ Σ ∂ φ) that used to work in 4.0.62 now saves ? in the DB.

Has anything changed that could cause that breaking change. We did not change the save code, and breakpoint just before save clearly shows the correct characters.

This is basicaly the code we are executing:

```
DB.Save<DTOType>(dtoInstance)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going through ServiceStack ORMlite code and found out about this:

OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.GetStringConverter().UseUnicode;

So I trying that calling

```
OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.GetStringConverter();
```

just before the DB.Save call returned false, which would explain the issue, as this would set the dbCmd to use VARCHAR instead of NVARCHAR

I set

```
 var stringConverter = OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.GetStringConverter();
 stringConverter.UseUnicode = true;
```

at AppHost initial configuration and that fixed the issue.

Apparently I cannot read documentation properly as it was described here

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/wiki/OrmLite-Type-Converters

Answer (score 1):

The major change that may have affected this is switching to [paramaterized queries in v4.0.60](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.0.60#ormlite). OrmLite typically itself doesn't do any encoding for normal string properties, i.e. it just passes the string value into the ADO.NET DB parameter.

The main time it transforms strings values is when it [serializes complex types into blobs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#pluggable-complex-type-serializers).

The issue may be end up being in using an upgraded version of the ADO .NET provider.

Comment: Hmmm, the version that we upgraded from is 4.0.6.2. Higher than 4.0.6.0.   And I'm not sure to understand what you mean by " issue maybe end up in using an upgraded version of the  ado.net provider"

Comment: @scoob I see that, but I don't know of any other change affecting behavior since the string value is used in parameterized queries behind the scenes.

Comment: I found the answer, see my other answer. Maybe this behaviour changed between 4.062 to 5.0.0.0 I don't know. A suggestion would be to easily make full documentation state of past ServiceStack Versions easily available. ServiceStack changes quickly, not everybody updates to the latest, and since documentation reflects the latest version, it can get confusing if you are working with an older build.

Comment: @scoob release updates documentation is available on http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/ and http://docs.servicestack.net/release-notes-history for older releases